# How to pass a Multi-dimensional array to pyopencl.algorithm.copy_if() -- PyOpenCL,

Tags: python, c, opencl, pyopencl

The following codes gives me the warning "warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing '__global int' to parameter of type '__global int *'; take the address with &" and doesn't produce the desired result.

```
import pyopencl as cl  
import pyopencl.array
import pyopencl.algorithm
import numpy as np     

platform = cl.get_platforms()
my_devices = platform[0].get_devices(device_type=cl.device_type.ALL)
ctx = cl.Context(devices=my_devices)
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

aryary = np.array([[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17], [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0], [108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], np.int32)
cl_aryary = cl.array.to_device(queue, aryary)
lenary = np.array([8, 4, 1], np.int32)
cl_lenary = cl.array.to_device(queue, lenary)

result = cl.algorithm.copy_if(
  cl_aryary, 
  "sum_array(ary[i], len[i]) == 108", 
  extra_args=[('len', cl_lenary)], 
  preamble='''
    int sum_array(__global int *a, int num_elements)
    {
       int i, sum=0;
       for (i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
       {
       sum = sum + a[i];
       }
       return(sum);
    }  
  ''', 
  queue=queue
)

print(result)
```

EDIT: for reference:

https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/algorithm.html#module-pyopencl.algorithm

Comment: Where do you call the function sum_array? I think, there is the parameter `a` which is not put in correctly as pointer or as array. Isn't it to be: `"sum_array(&ary[i], len[i]) == 108",` ?

Comment: It gets called in the line "sum_array(ary[i], len[i]) == 108" which is evaluated for each member of the submitted array as "ary". I was thinking that ary[i] would pull out the constituent arrays, but not sure what is happening. The multidimensional array is getting flattened somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call of the function `int sum_array(__global int *a, int num_elements)` is in the line `"sum_array(ary[i], len[i]) == 108",` but there should be a pointer instead of the element of the array as defined in the function. That would be:
`"sum_array(&ary[i], len[i]) == 108",`

Comment: This appears to be correct. Working through another variable type mismatch error in my code now; will confirm once i have it actually working.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's my C code. I'm not a C programmer. The error: <program source>:817:47: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned long' and 'const psc_index_type' (aka 'const int')
                if (psc_K * psc_LID_0 + psc_k < psc_offset_end)

Comment: I can't find any ` psc_index_type` nor psc_K, psc_LID_0, aso, C gives this warning when you mix up signed and unsigned types, especially with compare functions linke `<` it is dangerous to mix it or cast these different types.